# specifying path for a file in python

Tags: python, filesystems

I am trying to access a file(image) in python. But it says No such file or directory

This is my file structure-
home->mrisa3->mrisa->src->program.py and the image

I have tried using absolute and relative path. But `os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns empty.

Here is my code:

```
import base64
import os
def basesix4(file):
    encoded_string = ""

    with open(file, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    return encoded_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = os.getcwd()
    filename=os.path.join(file,'image.jpeg')
    print(filename)
    print(basesix4(filename))
```

this is the output i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basesix4.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(basesix4(filename)[:70])
  File "basesix4.py", line 6, in basesix4
    with open(file, "rb") as image_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/apeksha/mrisa3/mrisa/src/image.jpeg'
```

But the line `print(filename)` is printing
`/home/apeksha/mrisa3/mrisa/src/image.jpeg`

Comment: Just because `print` prints the same filepath doesnt mean it actually exists. You can only find that out by querying the OS about it. In this case via `open`.

Comment: are you sure your image files ends with "jpeg" and not with "jpg"?

Comment: ``print(filename)`` prints the path because you say to print it, not because the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the directory of the file:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

add to it the file name and you have the file path.

Comment: As the others mentioned, you need to verify if your path exists and if it is valid. Try right clicking your file then proprieties, or test its path in the terminal.